# Matlab execute function each cell Matrix with matrix and cell postion as arguments

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I need to apply a function to each pixel of each image in a set of ~400 images. The function I wrote (called `customf`) requires 3 arguments: the matrix, and the position of the cell in the matrix (`m` and `n`). The position of the pixel is needed in order to compute the LBP (local binary pattern) which requires the values of surrounding pixels.
`customf(matrix, m, n)` returns an integer `d` so that `0 < d < 256`, and I would like to store each value of `d` in a matrix of the same size as my image.

given that the set is quite large, I'd like my code to be as efficient as possible, but I don't understand how to use `cellfun` or `arrayfun` in such a way.

or is it a better solution? (using nested `for` might be inefficient?)

thanks!

Comment: What are `n` and `m` needed for in your function `customf`? Only to identify the current cell, or also for computation?

Comment: customf requires m and n in order to compute the local binary pattern of each pixel, which requires the values of the adjacent pixels
( http://164.125.234.242/~prascat/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Computer-vision-using-LBP.png )

Comment: unfortunately I don't see how to avoid the NxM loop, but moving it _inside_ the function should help slightly (avoiding the overhead of NxM constant function calls). You could rewrite the function so that it loops over the whole image (or optionally only a small patch whose boundaries are specified as parameters) and returns the computed pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write `customf` in a different way? Instead of working on the *entire* image for each pixel (`m`, `n`), why don't you give it only a *local patch* required for computing the LBP of the patch's central pixel?

For example, if `customf` needs to look at pixels -/+ `k` away from `m`, `n` to compute the response `d` at `m`, `n`, then you may have

```
k = 5;
localF = @( patch ) customf( patch, k+1, k+1 ); % assuming patch is of size (2k+1)x(2k+1)
% apply LBP to an image
D = nlfilter( image, [2*k+1 2*k+1], localF );
```

Note that [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) zero-pads `image` in order to obtain `D` with the same size as `image`.